# Choice of the right stepper motor

Tags: arduino, antenna, stepper-motor, bidirectional

I need to make a precise angular rotator for my directional antenna. The goal is to rotate the antenna at a precise angle. Arduino stepper motor library has functionalities to run a stepper motor for one step at a time. However, the problem is to choose the right motor.

I need at least 1-degree precision. Therefore, I am thinking to use a 0.9-degree step angle stepper motor. The problem is I cannot decide what would be the right stepper motor for me.

The total weight of my system is 3 kg. There will be two directional antennas, each having 1 kg weight, in an antenna stand which has approximately 1 kg weight. I need to rotate the antenna at a specific angle and then make some experiments, and then go to the next rotation angle. Each time I need to achieve a precise angle so that the experiment can run correctly.

Now, what should be the right stepper moto for me? I can calculate the moment of inertia of my system (J). However, I do not know which torque would be sufficient to perfectly rotate this motor. That what should be the minimum angular acceleration (a) of my system to ensure a precise and smooth run of the system.

Comment: I'd suggest you need a 3:1 pulley (look for GT2 Pulleys, very common, 20T and 60T) and a Stepper motor controller with x8 microstep. With a very common 1.8deg stepper that will give you 0.075 deg per step. This will give roughtly 13 steps per degree.  It's not clear from your question exactly what mass you are rotating ..1 Kg, 2 Kg or 3 Kg.

Comment: Using a reduction pulley is a good idea.  You need to quantify the weight, required angular acceleration and the holding torque requirements (wind, imbalanced load, etc) to figure out what you need for a motor.  If precision is more important than speed and things are reasonably well balanced, a NEMA 17 stepper will probably be plenty [there is a wide range of holding torque at the NEMA 17 size].  There is no minimum acceleration to ensure precise and smooth operation, they are independent variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The total weight I need to rotate is 3 kg.

However, how accurate the micro-stepping is? A Very precise angular position is the most important part of my research.